# java - How to use google finance currency converter api?

Tags: java, android

i wanna know how to use "Google finance Converter" in android. Here is the url = https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=EGP&meta=ei%3DoBtUWanyG4rDU-6ygbAK i can write the amount, from, to. but i can't get the result because it's html, So how to get it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use google finance in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803326/how-to-use-google-finance-in-android-studio)

Comment: You can use this:https://github.com/hav3n/CurrencyConverter

Comment: if you want to stick to google finance you can use the base url: `https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=AED&to=ZWL`

Comment: I don't want stick to google finance, i just didn't find another one who has alot of currencies and for free, i used "rate-exchange.appspot.com" but it is down now, so i need another one like it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be real useful but you can get result

First thing, you need country code from google finance.

Then web request to url using:

`https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=AED&to=ZWL`

Here AED is from country code and ZWL is to country code.

Then you can parse the html to get:

```
<div id=currency_converter_result>1 AED = <span class=bld>87.7634 ZWL</span>
<input type=submit value="Convert">
</div>
```

I don't know java but sure there will be elegant web request and html parser.

Comment: it's easier than you think.